# FTP access blocked despite rule opened

Tags: firewall, ftp, windows-firewall

I am setting up FTP service on a Win 11 Pro machine. I enabled the FTP rules in Windows Defender Firewall as below:

[image]

However, on a neighboring PC, I couldn't telnet to port 21. But if I shut down the Windows Defender Firewall totally, then it works. This should confirm that the FTP server is running fine.

Where/what else could be blocking FTP access?

Under General/Action in each rule, the option selected is `Allow the connection`.

Comment: Have you checked 1) whether the rules are port-based or program-based, and if they're program-based, whether they actually match the FTP server .exe that you're using, 2) whether they allow the correct addresses in the "Scope" tab?

Comment: Thanks. The rule was created by Microsoft, but the applicable program was `svchost`! The rule is predefined and the settings are disabled. So I created another new rule to allow for port 21 and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The rule was created by Microsoft, but the applicable program was svchost! The rule is predefined

That indicates the rule was meant for use by the IIS FTP service built into Windows. If that's not the FTP service you're using, you need to create custom rules (if the service didn't create any automatically).

If you're creating port-based rules, don't forget to allow both FTP control (port 21/990) and FTP passive data ports (to match the passive range configured in your FTP server).

Comment: Mmm... I am using the built-in FTP service in Windows, so I guess that's part of IIS?